# Ethernet wall plate won't come off

Tags: ethernet

[image]

My wall plate won't come off - I've removed the screw on it, I can force the bottom part away from the wall as shown in the picture, but it seems there is some attachment behind the the top part.

Has anyone run into this kind of wall plate? How should I remove the wall plate from the wall? (I need it come off so that I could check the wiring - Originally it was used as a phone jack, now I would like to [use it for ethernet](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/226770/use-cat5e-for-network-instead-of-phone)).

Comment: Yeah, that's a *standard* wall plate form-factor; every 1-gang junction box uses it.  Electrical experts would instantly recognize that form-factor and known about the second screw location cleverly under the name plate.  The purpose of the name plate is to let you stick a slip of paper there which identifies the punchdown number.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The plastic rectangle at the top is on top of the 2nd screw. Stick a paper clip or a very small screwdriver on the side to push under and bend it slightly and it will pop out. Unscrew. Done.